# Unable to show Toast message using Ionicframework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, toast

I am extremely new to the world of mobile development and I am working with ionic framework.

All I am trying to do is to display a toast message to the user by following this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/show-native-toast-notifications-using-ionic-framework/) and so far I am just going crazy trying to implement it.

The error I get is as following

> Cannot read property 'toast' of undefined

1. I have [installed](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) cordova
2. I have [installed](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/toast/) the Toast plugin

inside my index.html I have added the script of `ng-cordova.min.js`

```
  <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Do i need to add the `Toast.js` file in index.html too? If yes then that does not help either and leads to another error.

This is my controller

```
  .controller('UsersController', ['$scope', '$http', '$cordovaToast', function ($scope, $http, $cordovaToast) {

    $scope.showToast = function() {
      $cordovaToast
        .show("Here's a message", 'short', 'center')
        .then(function(success) {
          console.log('Success');
        }, function (error) {
          console.log('Error');
        });
    };
  }
  ]);
```

What am i missing here?

I will really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

After making changes, suggested by @Del, the following error appears

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaToastProvider <- $cordovaToast <- UsersController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaToastProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaToast%20%3C-%20UsersController
    at ionic.bundle.js:13380
    at ionic.bundle.js:17574
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17579
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17753)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:17770)
    at ionic.bundle.js:22326
    at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:56883)
    at Object.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:54995)
```

Comment: Platform specific function will work on Emulator / real device.  Try same thing with emulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the plugin is correctly installed, I have used it without using $cordovaToast

```
.controller('UsersController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.showToast = function() {
      window.plugins.toast
        .show("Here's a message", 'short', 'center')
        .then(function(success) {
          console.log('Success');
        }, function (error) {
          console.log('Error');
        });
    };
  }
  ]);
```

You dont have to add the ng-cordova or toast.js.

If you add the plugin (ionic plugin add ...), remove the platform, add again, and build, it should work

Comment: I installed it via command `cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git` i did not do `ionic plugin add ....` i dont think this should have any difference

Comment: Its ok that instalation. ionic plugin is an alias of cordova plugin. Then test my solution, and post your results :)

Comment: I have updated my question and added the error I get after making the changes you suggested. Please see the section UPDATE

Comment: Do you still have any '$cordovaToast' reference in your code?

Comment: @nope I am using your example

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to run `$cordovaToast` on browser. It will not work because it is a native plugin. Please use it on a real device or emulator.

Comment: @saadia [this](https://github.com/mjunaidsalaat/TheFoodShop) is my portfolio ionic project and [this](https://github.com/mjunaidsalaat/TheFoodShop/blob/master/www/js/controllers/cartController.js) is the controller where i implemented the `$cordovaToast`. it was working perfectly fine. Please review this project. If you have any question ask here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: and I have question that if you have implemented Del's method of using `window.plugins.toast` why the `$cordovaToast` exception is coming in your error. Review it too.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, i did end up seeing the toast in emulator

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in ionic but I have little knowledge about android so then I found the way how to use android functions in ionic means I found the way to create own plugins from [here.](http://moduscreate.com/plugin-authoring-cordova-6-ios-android/)

so after following steps from the given link I have created an own plugin
you can see it [ionic plug @ github](https://github.com/pookie13/IonicPlug).

you need to follow simple 4 steps mentioned at git link.

hopefully, it will help you to sort out the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error will not go away on the real device as well unless you inject the dependency for $cordovaToast. You may use or may remove $cordovaToast in the controller and it will not affect the working. It is good practice to keep dependencies. The crucial step which is missing in all the responses is to introduce DI for ngCordova in the module to which UsersControllers belongs. 
The example highlighted by [JSalaat](https://github.com/mjunaidsalaat/TheFoodShop) has this controller

> foodShop.controller('cartController', function($scope, cartFactory,
>   $cordovaToast)

and the foodshop module has injected ngCordova.

> var foodShop = angular.module('foodShop',
>   ['ionic','firebase','ngCordova'])

As the plug-in belong to ngCordova it does not need to be introduced separately in the controller. This explains why there is no error in that application.

in your case try the app instance creation could look like

> var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

if not you will continue to have the Unknown provider: $cordovaToastProvider error

Answer (score 0):

For the record: For Ionic v2/v3

1. Install dependencies
2. Include it in ionic project
3. How to use it.

### 1. Install dependencies

Within CLI run below commands:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/toast
```

### 2. Include it in ionic project

1.Add below to `app.module.ts`

```
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
```

....and to `@NgModule` section `providers:[ HERE,]`

2.Each page where you want to use Toast you need to add:

```
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
```

....also add to constructor

```
constructor(private toast: Toast, ...){}
```

...now you can use it as below example:

```
this.toast.show('message', 'duration', 'position').subscribe();
```

...or sending message to console:

```
this.toast.show('message', 'duration', 'position').subscribe(
  toast=>{
    console.log(toast);
  }
);
```